# XRef vs Xref (.NET naming)

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

Which name is more consistent with .NET naming standards for properties and methods?

1.

```
public string XRef { get; set; }
```

2.

```
public string Xref { get; set; }
```

Comment: Since one of the MSDN guidelines is to avoid abbreviations, it could be argued that 'CrossReference' is more consistent than either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the first - the "X" is effectively a separate word (cross). This is a bit like the `CData` class (and `XCData`). It does look a bit odd, but I think it's worth indicating that the "R" is effectively the start of a word.

On the other hand, for a variable I'd probably use `xref` rather than `xRef`, simply because that latter looks *really* weird.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your code conventions, I think. I'd write `XRef` because `xref` is not one word, it contains X and Ref, and each word we should start with upper case letter.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Design Guidelines for Class Libraries (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx), I believe you'd end up with `XRef`.

1. X is not an acronym (acronym must be two or more characters)
2. `XRef` is not a compound word or common term.
3. Therefore, the Capitalization Rules for Identifiers comes into play. That says use Pascal casing. That would say capitalize the first letter in the identifier (X) and the first letter of each concatenated word (Ref).

I think, in the end, it really depends on what your coding standards are.